# How to show no boundary wave function satisifies Wheeler-de-Witt equation?

Tags: cosmology, quantum-gravity

I've seen various places it says the no boundary wave function (Hartle Hawking state) satisfies the Wheeler-de-Witt equation. But I don't think I've seen a proof. Is there a proof of this somewhere? Or a simple argument?